# Getting 400 bad request on post, but this post worked just before

Tags: angular, http, post

I have an angular 9 / Java 8 application, which i'm calling lots of post method everywhere.
But i have one which doesnt work every time.

When i test it, it works perfectly several times (3, 4 times) and suddenly, it will pop an error 400 bad request and i will not be able to do this post call anymore. But i can perfectly use other post methods in my application.

This is my post call:

```
this.subscriptions.push(
this.warehouseService.createWarehouseOpeningHoursProfiles(this.warehouseOpeningHoursProfiles).subscribe((wohp: WarehouseOpeningHoursProfile) => {
    if (!wohp) {
        this.toastService.notify('A profile already exists with these parameters');         
        this.loaderService.isLoading(false);               
    } else {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.loaderService.isLoading(false);
    }
},
error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.loaderService.isLoading(false)
}));
```

Please note the "error" is completly empty when it throwns.

This is my service call:

```
public createWarehouseOpeningHoursProfiles(warehouseOpeningHoursProfiles: WarehouseOpeningHoursProfile[]): Observable<WarehouseOpeningHoursProfile> {
    return this.restService.post(`${environment.url_warehouse_opening_hours_profiles}`, warehouseOpeningHoursProfiles, undefined, true);
}
```

I know the URL is ok and this call works perfectly because i created some profiles just before.

and the log in the console
[image]

If you need more informations, just ask me.

If someone have some ideas, I'm starting to run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A 400 means that the warehouseOpeningHoursProfiles object sent by the client to the server having some issues. it means JSON is invalid.
may be some speelings are wrong

Check with the api specification and the json payload

Comment: I add a corrupt data on the environment i was testing... And didn't saw it before check the payload. Thanks :)

Comment: @B.Champaux is it working now?

Comment: Yes, I updated the corrupt data in my database and it worked perfectly.